# Graph API sendMail not working after deployment

Tags: azure, email, microsoft-graph-api

I am following this turorial [SendMail](https://medium.com/medialesson/how-to-send-emails-in-net-with-the-microsoft-graph-a97b57430bbd)

I am able to get it working from my local but it gives 204 error when I deploy it. I have made sure that there is no Key Vault issue and all secrets are correct and accessible.

```
   public async Task<string> SendEmail(string fromAddress, string toAddress, string subject, string content)
        {
            try
            {
                
                
                string? tenantId = "";

                string clientId = "";
                string clientSecret = "";
                var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
                ClientSecretCredential credential = new(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, new TokenCredentialOptions { AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud });
                GraphServiceClient graphClient = new(credential, scopes);

                Message message = new()
                {
                    Subject = subject,
                    Body = new ItemBody
                    {
                        ContentType = BodyType.Text,
                        Content = content
                    },
                    ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>()
            {
                new Recipient
                {
                    EmailAddress = new Microsoft.Graph.EmailAddress
                    {
                        Address = toAddress
                    }
                }
            }
                };

                bool saveToSentItems = true;

                await graphClient.Users[fromAddress]
                 .SendMail(message, saveToSentItems)
                 .Request()
                 .PostAsync();

                return "Email successfully sent.";

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this._logger.LogError(ex, "error sending email");
                return null;
            }
        
        }
```

Comment: Response code 204 is not an error. It indicates that a request has succeeded. Do you catch any exception? If yes please share details including message etc.

Answer (score 0):

> I am able to get it working from my local but it gives a 204 error when I deploy it

I agree with @user2250152, the response code 204 is not an error.

According to the 204 HTTP response, The server successfully processed the request, but there is no content to return, When a request is granted but the server is unable to provide the client with the requested information, this might occur.

While it looks like the email was delivered successfully in your situation, the API has returned no content. By checking the recipient's email account to see if they received the email, you can confirm this.

I used the below code to send an email to the recipients with contents using C#.

**Code:**

```
    using Microsoft.Graph.Models;
    using Microsoft.Graph;
    using Azure.Identity;
    using System.Net.Mail;
    
    var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
    var tenantId = "your-tenant-id";
    var clientId = "your-client-id";
    var clientSecret = "your-client-secret";
    var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
        tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);
    
    var requestBody = new Microsoft.Graph.Users.Item.SendMail.SendMailPostRequestBody
    {
        Message = new Message
        {
            Subject = "Meet for lunch?",
            Body = new ItemBody
            {
                ContentType = BodyType.Text,
                Content = "The new cafeteria is open.",
            },
            ToRecipients = new List<Recipient>
            {
                new Recipient
                {
                    EmailAddress = new EmailAddress
                    {
                        Address = "venkatxxxx@hgmail.com",
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    };
    var result = graphClient.Users[""].SendMail.PostAsync(requestBody);
```

**Output:**

The above code was executed successfully and sent an email to the recipient's address.

[image]

**Reference:**

[user: sendMail - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)